# Using default button drawable in selector for Android application

Tags: android, button, android-selector

Currently I am using this selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true"
   android:drawable="@color/green" /> <!-- pressed -->
  <item android:state_focused="true"
   android:drawable="@color/green" /> <!-- focused -->
</selector>
```

I want my to set default drawable for my button in case it is not pressed and not focused. How should I modify my selector to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button" 
        android:state_focused="false" 
        android:state_pressed="false" 
        android:state_selected="false"/>
    <!-- Pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" 
        android:state_focused="false" 
        android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:state_selected="false"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. Settings for pressed and focused states works fine for me. I just need to get standard drawable for non pressed and not focused state.

Comment: @MykhailoGranik the comment is somewhat misleading. Try the code out.

Answer (score 0):

Define different colors for various states as follows (please use your own hex codes for colors) in a **res/values/colors.xml** file

```
<color name="green_pressed">#ff00f000</color>
<color name="green_focused">#ff00f700</color>
<color name="green_default">#ff00ff00</color>
```

Declare various drawables for different states

**button_focused_green.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="@color/green_focused" />
    <!-- optional, remove if you don't want round border -->
    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
</shape>
```

**button_pressed_green.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="@color/green_pressed" />
    <!-- optional, remove if you don't want round border -->
    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
</shape>
```

**button_default_green.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="@color/green_default" />
    <!-- optional, remove if you don't want round border -->
    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
</shape>
```

Declare a `StateListDrawable` in xml file which will be applied to the `Button`

**button_green.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused_green" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed_green" android:state_pressed="true"/>        
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_default_green"/>

</selector>
```

Set the background attribute of `Button` in your layout xml

```
<Button 
    ...
    android:background="@drawable/button_green"
.../>
```

Hope this helps.